# onblur, mousedown and settimeout 0

Tags: javascript

This is a theoretical question rather than something practical, I'm interested in whats happening and why, obviously in reality you could just use onclick or mouseup which both occur after the onblur.

Given a textbox and a button, the textbox has an onblur event, the button has a mousedown

Someone enters text and hits the button

The order of events is

```
button mousedown
textbox onblur
```

I guessed you could effectively reverse this order by using setTimeout to push some function to the back of the javascript queue, something like the below

```
function MyMouseDownCaller(func)
{
    return function (e)
    {
        var that = this;

        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            func.call(that, e);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

I was surprised it doesn't work, I assumed the queue would get a mousedown event and a onblur event at the same time, then the settimeout would call func after the onblur.

What's really happening here?

Comment: Actually if your button is submit for some form, native form submit action will done anyway. You need to listen `'submit'` event of the form and do there `event.preventDefault()` to prevent form submitting

Comment: Ok, I'll change submit to mousedown and same question applies

Comment: No, no `onclick`, you need to catch `onsubmit` event of your form to prevent submitting, not click of the submit button. And then, when you prevent submitting, the rest of your listeners will execute normally

Comment: I think, it is bubbling of events. To input in textbox you click on it. Event bubbles up and you get mousedown event before blur